# Bitrix, Как оценить скорость работы сайта с помощью API?

Tags: php, битрикс, api

Как с помощью специального инструмента Bitrix Framework определить страницу, время генерации которой наибольшее и на странице вывести самую ресурсоемкую страницу и ее долю % в общей статистике нагрузки.

Comment: посмотрите как это делает битрикс и просто скопируйте себе на отдельную страницу

Comment: Я посмотрел исходник там просто ссылка /login/?show_page_exec_time=Y&show_include_exec_time=Y&show_sql_stat=Y&login=yes

Comment: эм... это отладка на странице конкретной.
вам нужно сюда смотреть /bitrix/admin/perfmon_panel.php?lang=ru

Comment: я просто сейчас готовлюсь к сдаче второго экзамена по битриксу и на сколько я понял, должна быть функция в api для этого. Так как задание такое: С помощью специального инструмента Bitrix Framework определить страницу, время генерации которой наибольшее, для этого запустить анализ производительности и открыть все ссылки из верхнего меню по несколько раз. На странице /ex2/time_control/ написать текстом /ex2/time_control/ самую ресурсоемкую страницу и ее долю % в общей статистике нагрузки.

Comment: Тогда вам туда, куда я указал. Вы просто вручную запускаете тестирование, ходите по сайту, по всех страницах. А потом просто на `/ex2/time_control/` пишите, как вам указали текстом ответ тот, который вы увидели в админке. Работы с кодом в даном задании по факту 0.